# How can I retain connection credentials across calls in System.DirectoryServices?

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to connect to an Active Directory domain (W2K8R2 DC) in a different forest. To that end, I pass the credentials into the following DirectoryEntry constructor:

```
DirectoryEntry(string path, string username, string password, AuthenticationTypes authenticationType)
```

This is all good and well. What I *would* like to do though is retain the connection somehow and reuse it through all my calls to the AD so that I do not need to pass the credentials repeatedly. Is this possible somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: I just found out that System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement contains functionality like that; this won't work for me though because I need to access arbitrary fields from the Active Directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the control at the connection level, I recommend you to use [System.DirectoryServices.Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx). You can reuse your LDAP connection to make different LDAP queries. However, the programming paradigm is very different from `DirectoryEntry`

If you need to use `DirectoryEntry`, you have to store the username and password somewhere and then pass them to all the `DirectoryEntry` objects.  What I would do is to write a method `GetDirectoryEntry(string dn)` and have this method create the `DirectoryEntry` for me with the correct username and password. This doesn't look elegant but it doesn't do anything wrong. If you care password being stored in memory in plain text, use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) to store the password.

This is nothing wrong because `DirectoryEntry` is maintaining its own LDAP connection pool. If you have multiple `DirectoryEntry` with the same username and password, it will be smart enough to share the LDAP connection. It's basically the same as holding a single LDAP connection and doing different LDAP queries. It's not going to re-authenticate to LDAP server for each of the `DirectoryEntry` objects

If you don't like to rely on the black box feature from `DirectoryEntry`, the following suggested workaround may make you feel better.

```
static DirectoryEntry GetObject(DirectoryEntry root, string dn)
{
    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root))
    {
        searcher.Filter = "(distinguishedName=" + dn + ")";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
        if (result == null) return null;
        return result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    }
}
```

You just need to bind to a root object with username and password. Then, you can keep the root object as a static variable or whatever you like. Then, you get another `DirectoryEntry` object by doing a LDAP query with the `SearchRoot` set to your root object. The returned `DirectoryEntry` will still use the username and password from root. Again, this is not doing anything better than simply passing in username and password to `DirectoryEntry`. Indeed, performance-wise, it's worse because we need to do one more LDAP query to get the `DirectoryEntry`

Comment: Great - this looks very feasable; I think I'll go for the DirectorySearcher method. Thank you very much for your excellent and detailled answer!

Comment: This is beautiful. I needed to know if `DirectoryEntry` really was maintaining its own LDAP connection pool and if I should really be creating a new `DirectoryEntry` and associated `DirectorySearcher` every time I wanted to query the AD instead of having a singleton. This helped answer my question and refactor my code in confidence that the overhead in making the LDAP connection is only done once and all other `DirectoryEntry` instantiations utilize a connection pool functionality and avoid the LDAP connection overhead if possible. Thanks!