# How should I reduce connections to AD with DirectoryEntry within IIS?

Tags: c#, performance, active-directory, iis-7.5, directoryentry

I have a high volume website that creates and destroys an instance of DirectoryEntry for every request, and calls multiple searches using DirectorySearcher.

If the goal is to reduce the perceived load on ActiveDirectory (multiple login events), and to ideally reduce the physical load as well, what object reuse strategy is appropriate for this object?

Some things I'm considering:

- Singleton Pattern
- Object Factory (to handle multiple base DNs)
- Factory + ObjectPool (to handle load??)

What is the simplest way to solve this problem or is there a Factory/Pool pattern I could just plug into via Generics or some simple code editing?

Comment: What is the need/purpose, for creating and destroying DE's for every request? And for calling DS multiple times per request? Are you creating this load, or is it IIS itself? The more information you provide, the better the help. For example, I've seen lots of people getting the DE even though the DS have the data needed.

Answer (score 1):

`DirectoryEntry` will use connection pooling (reuse connections) as long as there is at least one undisposed `DirectoryEntry` for the same context (same domain, and credentials). There is a discussion of that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/connection-caching) (note that `DirectoryEntry` just wraps the native Windows ADSI interface), [here](https://dirteam.com/tomek/2007/08/09/system-directoryservices-and-connection-pooling/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954484/1202807).

There are also other ways to increase performance, like making sure you only ask for the attributes you need when you search (use [`PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload)). I discuss that in more detail in an article I wrote: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)