# How to Ldap Connection pool, with windows service, and reuse same connection?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, windows-services

The System create a connection pool to connect and manage connections to the active directory.
The goal is to create and reuse only one connection to a configured ad instead of to create for each request a new one.
Screenshot of the problem:
[Screenshot of the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlLK7.png)

Thing is, after the code implementations, and running the code on VStudio changes apply successfully, as shown bellow:
[Screenshot of the solution:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKIO0.png)

But After running the pipeline to deploy the service in my machine, issue still remains, as if no changes to the code were detected.It shows like the screenshot of the initial problem.

This is my first time working with windows services, so any inputs would be awesome.

Tried these, it works as expected:
[How can I retain connection credentials across calls in System.DirectoryServices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949152/how-can-i-retain-connection-credentials-across-calls-in-system-directoryservices/4954484#4954484)

so my code looks like this, and it creates the connection in a single place, whereas before these directoryEntry calls were all around the code...(50+ different places)

```
public async Task<DirectoryEntry> GetDirectoryEntry(string path, string username ="", string password = "", AuthenticationTypes authType = 0)
{
    try
    {
        var ldapMembershipProvider = GetCurrentLdapProvider(path);

        if (ldapMembershipProvider.UseSSL == true)
        {
            if (ldapMembershipProvider.SearchScope != "" && ldapMembershipProvider.SearchScope != null)
            {
                var conn = new DirectoryEntry(path + "/" + ldapMembershipProvider.SearchScope, username , password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);
                return conn;
            }
            else
            {
                var conn = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);
                return conn;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ldapMembershipProvider.SearchScope != "" && ldapMembershipProvider.SearchScope != null)
            {
                var conn = new DirectoryEntry(path + "/" + ldapMembershipProvider.SearchScope, username + "@" + ldapMembershipProvider.ShortName, password);
                return conn;
            }
            else
            {
                var conn =  new DirectoryEntry(path, username + "@" + ldapMembershipProvider.ShortName, password);
                return conn;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _loggingService.LogException("LdapConnectionService()", ex);
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

But Windows service with the code doesn't show the desired change.

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryEntry` wraps the Windows native ADSI (Active Directory Services Interface). The details on how ADSI handles connection caching is here: [Connection Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/connection-caching).

This is the important part to pay attention to:

> If the same server, port, and credentials are used in a subsequent connection, and only the ADS_FAST_BIND or ADS_SERVER_BIND authentication flags differ, ADSI will reuse the existing connection.

The method you wrote allows the caller to pass different server, port, credentials, and authentication type. And indeed, in your screenshot, it shows at least different ports and authentication type: both 389 and 636 are being used, which means LDAP and LDAPS. If you're using different credentials too, then that would explain multiple connections.

You also need at least one non-disposed object to keep the connection alive. So if all of your `DirectoryEntry` objects are either manually disposed, or garbage collected after going out of scope, then the next one you create will open a new connection.

Comment: regarding the 1st part of your answer, i make sure these credentials, server, port and authTypes are the same, because they are stored in the DB. So these information vary from client to client, but each client has only one configuration.

Comment: Can you give me extra details on the second part? This might be whats missing.

Comment: You screenshot shows connections to two different ports, so the configuration is definitely different.

Comment: What do you mean by the second part?

Comment: the first screenshot has two port connection, but that has already been taken care of. It was a GetPrincipalContext call, that was using the Default port i believe.
The Second Screenshot has the code with the changes that i have already applied. It seems like the changes are ok, as far as i can say, but the windows service after deploying the code does not reflect this. This is my question, is there anything else i should be looking for?

By second part i mean " need at least one non-disposed object to keep the connection alive..."

Thanks in advance.